# is ProjectTo < DTO > support Flattening?

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper

#### Code

```cs
 _doctorRepository.Where(t => t.Id == doctorId).ProjectTo<EmploymentDTO>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).FirstOrDefault()
```

#### Mapping configuration

```cs
            // doctor have  Navigation property Hospital
            CreateMap<Doctor, EmploymentDTO>().IncludeMembers(t => t.Hospital);                
            CreateMap<Hospital, EmploymentDTO>();
```

#### Expected behavior

```
SELECT TOP(1) [d].[Id], [d].[DepartmentId], [d].[DepartmentOther], [d].[DepartmentOtherCN], [d].[HospitalId], [d].[PositionId], [d].[PositionOther], [d].[PositionOtherCN], [d].[RankId], [d].[RankOther], [d].[RankOtherCN], [h].[City], [h].[Country], [h].[UniversityAffiliated], [h].[HospitalName], [h].[Province], [h].[CityCN], [h].[CountryCN], [h].[UniversityAffiliatedCN], [h].[HospitalNameCN], [h].[ProvinceCN]
FROM [Doctor] AS [d] WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN [Hospital] AS [h] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [d].[HospitalId] = [h].[Id]
WHERE [d].[Id] = @__doctorId_0
```

#### Actual behavior :

##### not left join hospital Table

```
SELECT TOP(1) [d].[DepartmentId], [d].[DepartmentOther], [d].[DepartmentOtherCN], [d].[HospitalId], [d].[Id], [d].[PositionId], [d].[PositionOther], [d].[PositionOtherCN], [d].[RankId], [d].[RankOther], [d].[RankOtherCN]
FROM [Doctor] AS [d] WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE [d].[Id] = @__doctorId_0
```

Comment: `.Find` executes the query. Use `.Where(x => x.Id == doctorId).ProjectTo<DTO>(...).FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: in my test project repository , Find  used  EF  Where，let you  misunderstood， I've revised。